# Javascript eval(0047) returns 39

Tags: javascript, eval

Why does eval(0047) return a value of 39? (047 and 00047 produce the same result)

And Why does eval(056) return a value of 46?

But...eval(0048) returns a value of 48, as expected!

It has something to do with the leading zeroes obviously, but I can't figure it out, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `eval`, you just need an integer literal beginning with `0` and where no digits are greater than 7 for JS to see that you're expressing [an octal literal value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal). For example:

```
console.log(011) // 9
```

Similarly for [hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal):

```
console.log(0xcd) // 205
```

See also the [Integers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Integers) section on MDN.

Comment: Aha now it makes sense, Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

It's octal, base 8. The 4 is the "8's" place, not the "10's" place.

4 * 8 = 32 + 7 = 39.